# How can I know what makes an incomplete type incomplete for error: arithmetic on a pointer to an incomplete type

Tags: c++, struct, instance, forward-declaration, point-cloud-library

I have tried to define my own PointT type to give me XYZRGBA and intensity values in a single point.  I tried to follow the conventions laid out in this article on the point cloud library website: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/adding_custom_ptype.php

The implementation for PointXYZRGBAI is in a .CPP file for one of my classes, but I forward declare it in a header file that is included by other header files. The implementation is in LidarFile.cpp:

```
struct PointXYZRGBAI{
  PCL_ADD_POINT4D;
  union{
    struct{
      float intensity;
      uint32_t rgba;
    };
    float data_c[4];
  };
  EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
} EIGEN_ALIGN_16;

POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT(PointXYZRGBAI,
                                  (float, x, x)
                                  (float, y, y)
                                  (float, z, z)
                                  (float, intensity, intensity)
                                  (uint32_t, rgba, rgba)
)

inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const PointXYZRGBAI& p){
  os << "(" << p.x << ", " << p.y << ", " << p.z << " - " << p.intensity << " - " << p.rgba << ")";
  return (os);
}
```

and the forward declaration is inside a header file name PointXYZRGBAI.h

```
#define PCL_NO_PRECOMPILE

#ifndef POINTXYZRGBAI_H
#define POINTXYZRGBAI_H
#endif

#include <pcl/point_types.h>

struct PointXYZRGBAI;

inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const PointXYZRGBAI& p);
```

From my very basic understanding of structs, I need to forward declare the struct so that the compiler understands that PointXYZRGBAI is indeed a struct and not some unknown type during compiling, and fills in the blanks afterwards with the actual implementation.  But this is seemingly challenged by the fact that when I declare any member instance variable that uses the templated type PointXYZRGBAI, an error is thrown: arithmetic on a pointer to an incomplete type 'PointXYZRGBAI, like when I declare a point cloud that uses the struct PointXYZRGBAI:

```
pcl::PointCloud<PointXYZRGBAI> cl; //Error: arithmetic on a pointer to an incomplete type 'PointXYZRGBAI'
//__alloc_traits::destroy(__alloc(), _VSTD::__to_raw_pointer(--__end_));
// __alloc_traits::destroy(__alloc(), _VSTD::__to_raw_pointer(--__end_));
```

It would appear that there are undefined operations taking place on the PointXYZRGBAI type. So what should I do? Do I need to somehow implement the struct before the LidarFile.h header? Just for reference, here is the full error stack trace:

```
In file included from /Users/wfehrnstrom/Demeter/core.cpp:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:17:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:24:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:424:68: error: 
      arithmetic on a pointer to an incomplete type 'PointXYZRGBAI'
        __alloc_traits::destroy(__alloc(), _VSTD::__to_raw_pointer(--__end_));
                                                                   ^ ~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:368:29: note: 
      in instantiation of member function
      'std::__1::__vector_base<PointXYZRGBAI,
      Eigen::aligned_allocator_indirection<PointXYZRGBAI> >::__destruct_at_end'
      requested here
    void clear() _NOEXCEPT {__destruct_at_end(__begin_);}
                            ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:451:9: note: 
      in instantiation of member function
      'std::__1::__vector_base<PointXYZRGBAI,
      Eigen::aligned_allocator_indirection<PointXYZRGBAI> >::clear' requested
      here
        clear();
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iterator:1244:75: note: 
      in instantiation of member function
      'std::__1::__vector_base<PointXYZRGBAI,
      Eigen::aligned_allocator_indirection<PointXYZRGBAI> >::~__vector_base'
      requested here
  ...<class _Tp, class _Alloc> friend class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY vector;
                                                                  ^
/Users/wfehrnstrom/Demeter/LidarFile.h:20:7: note: in instantiation of member
      function 'pcl::PointCloud<PointXYZRGBAI>::~PointCloud' requested here
class LidarFile{
      ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1527:14: note: 
      in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<LidarFile>
      >::__destroy<LidarFile>' requested here
            {__destroy(__has_destroy<allocator_type, _Tp*>(), __a, __p);}
             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:424:25: note: 
      in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<LidarFile>
      >::destroy<LidarFile>' requested here
        __alloc_traits::destroy(__alloc(), _VSTD::__to_raw_pointer(--__end_));
                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:368:29: note: 
      in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::__vector_base<LidarFile,
      std::__1::allocator<LidarFile> >::__destruct_at_end' requested here
    void clear() _NOEXCEPT {__destruct_at_end(__begin_);}
                            ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:451:9: note: 
      in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::__vector_base<LidarFile,
      std::__1::allocator<LidarFile> >::clear' requested here
        clear();
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iterator:1244:75: note: 
      in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::__vector_base<LidarFile,
      std::__1::allocator<LidarFile> >::~__vector_base' requested here
  ...<class _Tp, class _Alloc> friend class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY vector;
                                                                  ^
/Users/wfehrnstrom/Demeter/PointXYZRGBAI.h:9:8: note: forward declaration of
      'PointXYZRGBAI'
struct PointXYZRGBAI;
       ^
In file included from /Users/wfehrnstrom/Demeter/core.cpp:9:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:17:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:24:
```

Any help or clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without knowing what the `pcl::PointCloud` template is all about, the most likely answer is that this template attempts to instantiate an instance of its parameter class, or use it in some way that requires the class to be defined.

Comment: A **type** is *declared*. Its **members** are *implemented*. Declare your structure in a header.

Comment: Yes !  Or incrementing/decrementing/substracting pointers: as the size would have to be known

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do very few things with an incomplete type.

If you forward declare a `struct` or a `class` as you did, you can only declare a pointer to such an object:

- You can't even increment or decrement such a pointer because this would require the compiler to know the size of the object (i.e. know its declaration).
- You can't allocate a new object either, as the constructors are not known, and neither are the alignment requirements.

So you have to put the struct definition in the header:

```
#define PCL_NO_PRECOMPILE

#ifndef POINTXYZRGBAI_H
#define POINTXYZRGBAI_H

#include <pcl/point_types.h>

struct PointXYZRGBAI{
  PCL_ADD_POINT4D;  // macro in pcl/point_types.h that defines some member functions
  union{
    struct{
      float intensity;
      uint32_t rgba;
    };
    float data_c[4];
  };
  EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW  // eigen/core seems included in pcl/point_types.h 
} EIGEN_ALIGN_16;

inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const PointXYZRGBAI& p);

#endif
```

The implementation of the functions (and the registration macro) shall remain in the cpp file.

Comment: PLC_ADD_POINT4D is a trick that adds 8 member functions that construct some objects and return them by value.  Have you added the corresponding object files or library files in you linking instructions ?